# NSBundle mainBundle pathForResource: Not working unless @2x included

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, filesystems, nsbundle

I have files named: landing_load1@2x ...landing_load4@2x in my project. (No non-retina files)

This code works:

```
for(int x=1; x < 5; x++){
    NSString * imageTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"landing_load%i@2x", x];
    UIImage * loadingImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageTitle ofType:@"png"]];

    [loadingImages addObject:loadingImage];
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
for(int x=1; x < 5; x++){
    NSString * imageTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"landing_load%i", x];
    UIImage * loadingImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageTitle ofType:nil]];

    [loadingImages addObject:loadingImage];
}
```

And this doesn't work:

```
for(int x=1; x < 5; x++){
      NSString * imageTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"landing_load%i", x];
      UIImage * loadingImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageTitle ofType:nil]];

     [loadingImages addObject:loadingImage];
}
```

Question: I know I don't have to explicitly call @2x or specify the file type, so any ideas why it's not working unless I explicitly write the whole file name out?

Note: Tested on iPad 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record

```
NSString * imageTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"landing_load%i", x];
```

means that you have a pair of graphics files for any resource - both "filename.png" and "filename@2x.png".
Or, alternatively, it can be used as "alias" for only "filename.png"
If you have only "filename@2x.png", you have two possible variants:
1. Use something like that

```
NSString * imageTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:"landing_load%i@2x", x];
```

or have both of files ("filename.png" and "filename@2x.png") for any resource.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'non' working example you haven't stated `nil` in the `ofType` parameter.

```
 UIImage * loadingImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]     pathForResource:imageTitle ofType:nil]];
```

change to `png`, should do the trick :)

Comment: updated the question. Still doesn't work unless I add @2x. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using

```
-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]
```

method, you need to specify resource type in second parameter, which you were provided as "png" in the code you say it works.

Answer (score 0):

The @2x is handled as part of `[UIImage imageNamed:]` not as a part of `[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]`  Just use the former and you should be good to go.

Comment: imageNamed don't release image and cause memory problems